# How to change id of tanstack React Table useSelectRow

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

Hi guy I just do experiment on build bulk delete on tanstack React Table
the problem is here I can't change the id of the selected column

why do I want to change this? 
because I want MongoDB id that can send to the server.
with `selectedRowIds` method

[image]

here some code from hook

```
hooks => {
            hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
                // Let's make a column for selection
                {
                    id: 'selection',
                    // accessor: '_id',
                    // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
                    // to render a checkbox
                    Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
                        <div>
                            <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
                        </div>
                    ),
                    // The   cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
                    // to the render a checkbox
                    Cell: ({ row }) => {
                        console.log(row)
                        return <div>
                            <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
                        </div>

                    },
                },
                ...columns,
            ])
```

and all full reference comes from the [main documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/row-selection)

Answer (score 3):

There is an option you can pass to the `useReactTable` hook called `getRowId` that allows you to customize your row id.

```
getRowId?: (
  originalRow: TData,
  index: number,
  parent?: Row<TData>
) => string
```

https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#getrowid

Answer (score 0):

use `selectedFlatRows` is contian all selected row data

[image]